# Determine for which test setup() is being called?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, dagger-2

I'm writing Unit tests for my Android App using Mockito.
I'm using dagger 2 to switch between a Mock Client and a real client:

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    private boolean mMockMode;

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Client provideClient() {

        if (mMockMode) {
                return Mockito.mock(Client.class);
        }

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new StethoInterceptor());

        return new OkClient(okHttpClient);

    }

}
```

The client is injected into the tests like this:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BaseActivity> {  

    @Inject
    Client client;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        App app = (App) getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        app.setMockMode(true);
        app.component().inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithActualCall(){
        //code...
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithMockCall(){
        //code...
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        App.getInstance().setMockMode(false);
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the code, there are some tests that I wish to do with a mock api and others that I wish to do with the real api. In order to do this, I need to know for which test `setUp()` is being called so that I can change the argument of `setMockMode(boolean)` accordingly.

Is there a way I can find out which test is being `setUp()`?

Comment: They way you're mixing test and production code in the ApiModule class is a code smell, imo. Take a look at "module overrides" in the dagger docs for a better solution to use mocked injects: https://square.github.io/dagger/

Comment: @Bewusstsein The module overrides you linked to are a part of the original Dagger, not Google's Dagger 2 fork. That said, you're right about the smell, and you could easily make a module that extends ApiModule and overrides the `provideClient` method.

Answer (score 1):

Split up the tests into 2 classes, one with all tests that use the mocked API, the other with the real API.

Use what you have as a base class, move the value of `mockMode` into a method and then override that method in the other class:

```
public class MainActivityMockApiTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<BaseActivity> {  

    ...

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        ...
        app.setMockMode(isMockMode());
        ...
    }

    protected boolean isMockMode() {
        // overridden in MainActivityRealApiTest
        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```